# PHP SOAP Credentials in Header securityContext

Tags: php, soap, credentials

Im struggling with this 2 days and trying almost everything I found on internet. I have SOAP service with username and password in header securityContext but have no idea how to provide data in that form in PHP?

This is required header XML:

```
<soap:Header>
    <SecurityContext xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <userName>string</userName>
        <password>string</password>
    </SecurityContext>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, i managed it to work. Here is what is necessery if someone have similar problem.

Part for adding header values:

```
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
           $auth = array(
            'userName' => self::SOAP_USERNAME,
            'password' => self::SOAP_PASSWORD,
        );
    $header = new SoapHeader(self::SOAP_NAMESPACE, 'SecurityContext', $auth);
        $soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Also, because it's https request I needed to add some ssl options:

```
    // set stream context opts
    $opts = array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
        ),
    );
    // set options
    $options = array(
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout' => 15,
        'login' => self::SOAP_USERNAME,
        'password' => self::SOAP_PASSWORD,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    );
```